# Get the id of certain record in component

Tags: joomla

I have to delete the images related to the record that I am about to delete. What I did in `view.html.php` is

```
JToolBarHelper::trash('slideshows.customDelete', 'JTOOLBAR_TRASH');
```

Now it points to my `customDelete` function in the controller but how can I get the `id` of the chosen row. I am not an expert in Joomla, excuse if the question is pathetic.

Comment: No way to do it ?

Comment: Do you want to remove an item or a list of items? In which view are you in? Which component? Chosen row?

Comment: @Toma please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.